# Prefix or scope Vuex mapActions and mapGetters to avoid conflicts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm using **Vuex store** with a `user.module` that have **actions** and **getters**, i import theme in my components like so :

```
<template>
     ...

     <login-form v-if="!isAuthenticated"/>

     ...
</template>

<script>
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default { 

        ...

        computed :{
            ...mapGetters('user', ['isAuthenticated', 'isProcessing']),
        },
        methods:{
            ...mapActions('user', ['getUser']),
        }

        ...
    }
</script>
```

the script above work just fine, what i want is to **scope, namespace or add a prefix** to my actions and getters to avoid conflicts with other methods in my components, something like **`user.isAuthenticated`**, i tried those combinations, but none of theme did the job :

```
...mapActions('user', ['user/getUser'])
...mapActions('user', ['user.getUser'])
...mapActions('user/user', ['getUser'])
...mapActions('user.user', ['getUser'])
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the object syntax to map the actions to different names in the component:

```es6
...mapActions('user', {
  prefix_getUser: 'getUser',  // this.prefix_getUser -> user/getUser action
  prefix_getFoo: 'getFoo',    // this.prefix_getFoo  -> user/getFoo action
})
```

This is described in the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components).